# Emacs. How to diminish this ugly centered block?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When it is unable to scroll up, this strange block shows up. 
It's really ugly.
Any idea?
[screenshot http://vividart.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-19%20at%203.18.24%20PM.png](http://vividart.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-19%20at%203.18.24%20PM.png)

Comment: It is unlikely that block would show with a bare-bones current installation of Emacs.  Try running Emacs without any user configuration and if it works fine, then start commenting out your user configuration file until you track down the source of the problem.

Comment: @lawlist, it's due to (setq visible-bell t).

Comment: Would you prefer to make it work with a pretty picture, or would you like to just prevent it from appearing:  `(setq visible-bell nil)`

Comment: @lawlist How to make it work with a pretty picture?

Comment: It is the same way on OSX, i.e., an ugly black box flash and there are discussions on the Emacs mailing list going back several years in time -- I don't see anything by Googling that can turn that into a pretty bell shaped image.

Comment: figured it out. Assign a ring-bell-function does the work.

Comment: Zhang Kai Yu: Now you should add your solution (with code) as an answer, so that it will be useful to other people, and then accept that answer.